# Insertar HTML con directivas angular, contenido en un string, dentro de un contenedor

Tags: angular

Tengo esta cadena string, proveniente de una base de datos:

```
`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="propiedad">`
```

Necesito incrustar este string en el ng-container de este template:

```
<div [scrollTop]="scrollTopTexto" #cajaTexto>
      <ng-container></ng-container>
</div>
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme con esto? Gracias.

Comment: Revisa este ejemplo [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w1g4u7)

Comment: Esa opción ya la descarté. Si miras el código generado para los input, verás que  las directivas ngmodel aparecen sin compilar, es decir, solo como atributos planos y la varible bindeada la toma solo como valor de ese atributo. No está compilando el código Angular.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-container` se utiliza para usar estructuras de control de angular (ngFor, ngIf, ngSwitch, etc.) sin afectar el css lo que tu quieres incrustar html se puede hacer con.

```
<div [innerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>
```

O con

```
<div [outerHTML]="theHtmlString"></div>
```

Dependiendo de la estructura que le quieras dar, sin embargo, **angular no procesa html agregado posteriormente** con innerHTML, outerHTML por lo que **[(ngModel)]** no funcionaria y tendrías que agregar los eventos para escuchar ese input de otra forma. yo lo que te sugiero es usar `[hidden]=""` o `*ngIf=""` para mantener tus inputs ahí pero ocultos

Answer (score 0):

Al final he seguido las indicaciones de la documentación oficial y tras insertar el html sin directivas angular, mediante [innerHTML] en el contenedor, lo he referenciado como:

@ViewChild('htmlcontainer') htmlcontainer: ElementRef;

A continuación, he hecho uso de la API Renderer2 para manipular los inputs manualmente, con sus métodos y propiedades: [doc oficial Angular](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#description)